# Let $n\in\Bbb Z$ and let $f(x)=x^3-nx^2-(n+3)x-1$. Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $n\in Z$ and let $f(x)=x^3-nx^2-(n+3)x-1$.

1. Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$.
2. Show that if $r$ is a root of $f(x)$ then $-1/(1+r)$ is also a root of $f(x)$.
3. Compute the smallest field extension of $\Bbb Q$ where $f(x)$ factors completely into linear factors.

For the first part, I used Rational Root Theorem to show that $f(1)=-2n-3\ne 0$ since $n\in Z$ and $f(-1)=1\ne 0$. And any $a,b\in Z$ such that $a \nmid -1$ or $b \nmid 1$ implies $f(a/b) \ne 0$ hence $f(x)$ has no rational root and since its degree is 3, it is irreducible in $Q[x]$. Please let me know if that's correct.

For the second part, I evaluated $g(x)$ by long division where $f(x)=g(x)(x-r)$ and since if we assume $-1/(1+r)$ is a root, then $f(-1/(1+r))=0$ implying   $g(-1/(1+r))=0$. But I couldn't get $g(x)=0$ when evaluating at $-1/(1+r)$. So I couldn't solve part 2).

And similarly for 3), would smallest field extension of $Q$ be Q(r,-1/(1+r),R)? where R is the third root? I couldn't get any further either. Please let me know.

Comment: The implication that $g(-1/(1+r))=0$ is not warranted. Perhaps $r=-1/(1+r)$. You should just write $f(-1/(1+r))$ as a quotient of two relatively prime polynomials in $r$ and show that the numerator if divisible by the polynomial $f(r)$. You get that $f(-1/(1+r))=\frac{-f(r)}{(1+r)^3}$

Comment: For the third part, if $r$ and $-1/(1+r)$ are different roots, then the third root, as well as $-1/(1+r)$ will already be in $\mathbb{Q}(r)$. You need to study separately the problem under the assumption that $r=-1/(1+r)$.

Comment: I still don't know how to solve part 2) and 3). Also, is part 1) correct?

Comment: In my first comment (its last sentence) is the solution of part (2). Your argument for part (1) is correct. For part (3) first check that it is not possible that $r$ is a root of $f$ and $r=-1/(1+r)$. This is because this implies that $r^2+r+1=0$ and the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ doesn't divide $f(x)$, since the remainder is $-3x+n$. Therefore $r$ and $-1/(1+r)$ are actually two roots of $f$. Therefore, $f$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(r)$.

Comment: Ok, I understand part (2) and I followed your argument for part (3) up until where $r$ and $-1/(1+r)$ are actually two roots of $f$. But what about the third root of $f$? And how do we know $f$ splits in $Q(r)$?

Comment: If you already have two of the roots $r,-1/(1+r)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(r)$, then the third root is also in the field. For example, [the product of all the roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) should be equal to $-f(0)=1$. Thus, the third root is $(1+r)/r$.

Comment: Ok, got it. Just one more question, how do I know $-1/(1+r)$ is in $Q(r)$? Isn't $Q(r)=\{a+br+cr^2 | a,b,c\in Q\}$? So how can I express $-1/(1+r)$ in $Q(r)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(r)$ is a field, and since you proved that $1+r\neq0$, we can add $1+r$ and divide $-1$ by $1+r$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! The solution is simple after you explained it.

Comment: If you want $-1/(1+r)$ expressed as a polynomial in $r$ you can take $f(r)-1=-1$ and divide by $r+1$. You get that $-1/(1+r)=r^2-(n+1)r-2$.

Comment: Yes, then $-1/(1+r)=r^2-(n+1)r-2$ would be expressible in $Q(r)$.

Comment: +1 for showing effort. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @plop: may be you can put your comments as an answer. It appears they were really helpful to OP and will also help others who may not read all comments.

Comment: Also you just need to check for $1,-1$ as roots. If a monic polynomial with integer coefficients has a rational root it must be integer itself and a divisor of the constant term of the polynomial.

Comment: I already checked in my solution to part (a).

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $f$ has three distinct real roots: $r$, $-\frac{1}{1+r}$, and $-\frac{1+r}{r}$ (why?). It follows that its splitting field is $\mathbb Q(r)$.

For the second question: show that $f(-\frac{1}{1+r})=0$ using that $f(r)=0$. It is only a matter of calculation!